# Не могу подключится к бд mysql

Tags: java

Выводит вот такую ошибку
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

chat создан[image: скрин с Mysql]

пользователь root тоже есть
[image: скрин с Mysql]

Сам код:

```js
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBWorker {

  private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chat?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
  private static final String user = "root";
  private static final String password = "root";
  private static Connection con;

  public DBWorker() {
    try {
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }


  }

  public Connection getConnection() {
    return con;
  }
}
```

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:6627', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:6627', transport: 'socket'
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
Помогите исправить пожалуйста.

Comment: Программа и MySQL запущены на одном компьютере?

Comment: Да. MySQL 6.0.6,JDBC 5.1.23

Comment: Нужно использовать последнюю версию драйвера.

Comment: Поставил JDBC 7.2.Та же самая ошибка.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297356/mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-in-jdbc-program-at-run-time